# Kendo Grid edit event handler not updating row

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

When adding a new item to a Kendo Grid using inline editing, the `ContractID` datasource is filtered by the selected `OrgID`. Once a row has been added, the `OrgID` column is no longer editable (set using `isOrgEditable()`) but the `ContractID` is. Unfortunately the cascade doesn't then work for editing and the datasource for `ContractID` is unfiltered.

To resolve that issue I subscribe to the edit event (`data-edit="setContractsDataSource"`) and filter the data source manually. That works but then the Update button doesn't do anything and the edit is lost.

```
<div id="grid">
    <div class="k-content wide">
        <div>
            <div data-role="grid"
                 data-editable="inline"
                 data-edit="setContractsDataSource"
                 data-toolbar="[{ name: 'create', text: 'Add Item' }]"
                 data-columns='[
                 { field: "OrgID", title: "Company", editable: isOrgEditable, editor: orgDropDownEditor, template: "#: lookupForOrg(organisationID) #" },
                 { field: "ContractID", title: "Contract", editor: contractsDropDownEditor, template: "#: lookupForContract(ContractID) #" },
                 { command: ["edit", "destroy"], width: "220px" }
            ]'
            data-sortable="true"
            data-pageable="true"
            data-filterable="true"
            data-bind="source: items"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As is often the case, I resolved the issue while writing the question. For future reference, the reason it wasn't being updated was due to not returning `true` from the event handler:

```
function setContractsDataSource(e) {
    let orgID = e.model ? e.model.OrgID : this.dataItem().OrgID;
    if (orgID) {
        $("#contracts").data("kendoDropDownList").setDataSource(contractsData.filter(elt => elt.ContractorID == orgID));
    }
    return true; // fixed it
}
```

Subsequently established that the column would only update if it already contained a value, i.e. the new value wouldn't save if previously it had been empty. [This telerik forum post](https://www.telerik.com/forums/inline-dropdown-data-is-not-updated-when-change-from-empty-value#unSlqIrM5E2aqCLln6tXag) helped to resolve it. The editor for the Contracts column needed `valuePrimitive: true`.

```
function contractsDropDownEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input id="contracts" name="' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList({
            autoBind: false,
            dataTextField: "ContractNo",
            dataValueField: "ContractID",
            dataSource: contractsData,
            optionLabel: "Select contract...",
            valuePrimitive: true
        });
}
```